# Can't bootstrap/initialize a new Sitecore Commerce 9 instance on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, sitecore-commerce

Just starting messing with Sitecore Experience Platform/Commerce 9.0 update 1 on Azure's App Service, managed to deploy it fairly easily, but now I'm stuck during the bootstrap/initialization part.

As per their documentation, I've imported the "postman" folder from the root of the Commerce Engine SDK folder into Postman. I ran the **GetToken** call to get my SitecoreIdToken, it worked and the value got populated automatically in Postman.

Now I'm trying to run the **Bootstrap Sitecore Commerce** and **Initialize Environment** calls, but it doesn't work.

I've modified the default environment variable `HostName` to reflect my Azure App Service's URL, being `sxc-portal-587220-ops.azurewebsites.net`. I've left the `protocol` as `https`, and left everything else as-i.

When I run the command, which now expands to `PUT https://sxc-portal-587220-ops.azurewebsites.net:5000/commerceops/Bootstrap()` (for the **Bootstrap Sitecore Commerce** call), it times out. Same for the **Initialize Environment** call, which expands to `https://sxc-portal-587220-ops.azurewebsites.net:5000/commerceops/InitializeEnvironment(environment='EnvironmentName')`
If I try and access the ops URL by itself (`https://sxc-portal-587220-ops.azurewebsites.net`), I get the following error: `Status Code: 404; Not Found`.

Can anyone help me regarding this issue ? Would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked authoring and ops sites log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I got the answer from Sitecore's Slack team (who reached out to Sitecore as they had the same issue). 
It was a mix of JuanDanielGarza's answer, and kind of not!
It ended up being a simple issue of the pre-configured API calls from Sitecore that were hardcoded to use the Ops server's (not the CM instance) port 5000 for access.

The *Bootstrap Sitecore Commerce* API call looks like that when opened: `{{OpsApiHost}}/{{OpsApi}}/Bootstrap()`, while the *Initialize Environment* looks like this: `{{OpsApiHost}}/{{OpsApi}}/InitializeEnvironment(environment='{{Environment}}')`.

`{{OpsApiHost}}` is configured as such: `{{Protocol}}://{{HostName}}:5000`. `{{Protocol}} = https`, and `{{HostName}}` has to be configured with your Ops App Service's URL.`{{Environment}}` is already populated in the two environments that you load into Postman.

[image]

By changing the default port to 443 instead of 5000, it worked just fine, all the redirects in the backend were taken care of by the Ops server, and my Boostrapping and initialization calls succeeded without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

App Services only use ports 80 and 443, the hostname would normally be your CM instance and use ports 5000 and 5050 to redirect to the other hosts like ops and minions. replace the urls in postman with the webapps for each service as opposed to using the port 5000 redirects from the primary url. additionally make sure you selecting token auth for each POST/GET